# Should CW activity be rewarded similarly to normal posts?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, community-wiki

I wonder if votes on a community wiki should be rewarded as well like in the normal posts? If I understand the concept behind the voting system correctly, good or bad community wiki behavior could be rewarded or punished as it is a value-adding form of activity.

Of course, not applying the regular rep values, but more like a +1/-1 style, therefore, controversial wiki entries should net 0 for the answerer and for the display.

Other option would be to have badges for these purposes instead (do we have these already?)

(Note: I'd like a discussion with views, points and arguments, so when you post a "no, by design" answer, please explain it a bit at least.)

Comment: Hehe, I read this and thought "What does Morse code have to do with posting...".  :-)

Comment: @B.K.: Please, enlighten me.

Comment: You can already get the "nice answer" badge for a CW post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Community wiki posts are for topics that are generally open for discussion, and have no right or wrong answer. Also several users can contribute to create a more complete answer to a point where the original poster may have little or nothing to do with the reason the post is getting votes.

People are free to express their opinions in wiki posts without fearing loss of reputation. Because of this people are also far more likely to down vote you over a difference in opinion, although technically there is nothing wrong with your post. The aim is to get the most popular or most agreed upon solution, while no solution may be more correct than any other.

Comment: I see a contradiction here. Voting an answer vs. no right or wrong answer?

Comment: No, voting an answer in wiki's can simply mean you agree on the users opinion, it doesn't necessarily deal with technical correctness.

Comment: I see a contradiction again: so is wiki an opinion forum or a place to post correct answers, especially on technical questions?

Comment: Its not so much of a contradiction as a mixing of both. It allows users to collaborate on opinions, technical facts, and everything else without regard to exactly what the technically correct answer is, or on topics where there is no definitive 'correct answer'. That isn't to say that wikis don't contain correct information, it just means they don't have to.

Comment: Thanks. Just for a thought experiment: an assymetric rewarding of +1/-0 would be more suitable?